# Merge conflicts but no differences between commits

Tags: git, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I had this

```
a - b - g   master
     \
      c - d - e  topic
```

I rebased topic on master then I did some rebases inside master to get (say):

```
a - b - g - C' - E'  master
     \
      c - d - e  topic
```

but without introducing any changes in the rebase ! That is I squashed, rearranged etc but the net result of `C' - E'` was the same as `c - d - e`. Also IIRC I had no conflicts when I rebased over master. Then I went on like this:

```
a - b - g - C' - E'  master
     \
      c - d - e - h - i topic
```

When I tried to rerebase topic on master I got conflicts on `c`. I squashed together `c - d - e` to get:

```
a - b - g - C' - E'  master
     \
      C'' - h - i topic
```

and tried to rerebase. Then I got the most strange conflicts as below (abbreviated):

```
  <<<<<<< HEAD
++
++    #--Config Phase -----------------------------------------------------------
++    def getTypes(self):
++        return ['HAIR']
++
  =======

      #--Config Phase -----------------------------------------------------------
      def getTypes(self):
          return ['HAIR']

  >>>>>>> C''
```

The lines are identical ! What does this mean ? How does it come about ?

NB: this is not a whitespace issue

I resolve it by skipping the commit but something does not feel right here...

**EDIT:** [the conflicts](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tl4687dvaz64ju3/SO_24667035_conflicts.diff) produced with:

```
$ git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U | xargs awk '/<<<<< HEAD/,/>>>>>>/' >> c\
onflicts.diff
```

[and apiece of context for last conflict](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4m32yt50vvwcti6/SO_24667035_conflicts_context_of_last_one.diff)

Comment: Identical? Is there any difference in tab cs. space or eol style?

Comment: If you rebased `topic` onto `master`. why did you always draw it attached to commit `b`. Should the base of the branch not move forward to `master`?

Comment: @VonC: yes no line or eol - notice it will then show `+/-` line diffs in the lines that differed. Now it shows this `++` and normal content in the other file

Comment: @RobertRüger: I kept a reference to the old branch (imagine that `h - i` were there from the beginning on another branch)

Comment: @VonC: added the conflicts theyselvesss :)